# Adding custom Right Click Menu in Excel using VSTO C# (com addin)

Tags: excel, vsto

I want to add some custom options to context menu when user right clicks on a cell. I have fond some solutions but these are document level solutions or by using Addin Express.
I am building a COM Addin in VSTO C#.
Here is the example of required output.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether VSTO or Add-in Express is used for building the add-in. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is common for all kind of COM add-ins. You can read more about the Fluent UI which is used for customizing context menus in Office applications in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The whole process of customizing context menus is described in the [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) article.

Comment: Rather than plain links, post some basic code examples of how to create a context menu